# How I keep entity object after DataContext disposed?

Tags: linq, entity-framework, datacontext

I use this style when I get data from database

```
public class User
{
    public static List<User> GetUsers()
    {
        List<User> users = new Users();
        using ( var context = new DataContext())
        {
            users = context.Users.ToList();
        }

        return users;
    }
}
```

After I get data from database then I want to Filter user likes this

```
List<User> userResultList = User.GetUsers();   
userResultList.Where(u => u.IsActive == true);
```

But cannot filter and I get this error

> The ObjectContext instance has been disposed and can no longer be used
>   for operations that require a connection.

My Question :
Is possible way to filter result object after DataContext disposed?

Thank you very much for every support.

Update !!!

I think it possible if I create new DbContext in method scope that I want to retrieve data

Is it good enough approach?

Example

```
public class User
    {
        public static List<User> GetUsers()
        {
            List<User> users = new Users();

            var context = new DataContext())
            users = context.Users.ToList();

            return users;
        }
    }
```

Comment: What is your `IsActive` property implementation? Is it persisted property or some computed property?

Comment: I don't see a problem in the code you posted. You needed the DataContext for the retrieval part (in your case). Using linq you can filter the collection. So to answer your question, you can filter the list after the DataContext was disposed. Maybe the error has a different cause.

Comment: Is the list being serialized higher in the execution stack? Through WCF service, or similar?

Comment: no, it's not good approach.wrap context in a using statement is good. Plus, if you are doing MVC application, you probably don't want to create a new context in each action method.

Comment: What process actually triggers enumeration of `userResultList.Where(u => u.IsActive == true)` (which is just an enumerable that in itself does nothing)? It looks like some lazy load is triggered there.

Comment: I occur with GertArnold. 
I found answer happen when I wanna get related object with User Object. 
Example User has relation ship is one to one UserTransaction 

userResultList.where(u => u.UserTransaction.ID == 1) << Error rise here. Error message is same above error. But now anyone have any solution to track related object after DataContext dispose.
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I wonder if you clone the list will get around the error?

```
User[] L = new User[users.Count];
users.CopyTo(L);
```

Speculation:

What you had looks like it should work on the surface.

I wonder if the thing that is returned by ToList() is something that inherits from list, and retains some hidden context awareness inside.

I can't test this idea right now.  Something to think about for later though.